# c# android adding custom views to Linear Layout

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, dynamic, customization

I am using **LinearLayout.AddView** to add simple views.

I can add things, like textViews and editTexts, but I need to add 4 elements at once in a block with some parameters.

This is the block I would add dynamically.

[image: Here is the block]

It's a block with 4 layouts, the big one horizontal, left one vertical, 2 right horizontals.

[image: Layouts]

And here is the AXML for this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="88.0dp"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_weight="60">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:hint="Servizio" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:hint="Descrizione" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="32.5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
            <TextView
                android:text="€"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:layout_weight="20">
            <EditText
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_width="32.5dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
            <TextView
                android:text="€"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And you can imagine I can't achieve something like this adding elements one by one. And every time user wants, he should be able to iterate and add more of these blocks.

I dunno if i'm doing it the correct way, because even if I can add dynamically this block, how am I supposed to retrieve information in every single field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add the views dynamically, when the action is performed that causes the addition (say button click), inflate the layout and add it to the parent.

example:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_file, rootView);

            linearLayout.addView(view);
        }
});
```

However, as you want to have access to the input in all of these text fields, I'd suggest adding a custom view that uses the layout you've provided. This can then provide access to your EditTexts input. Store them either in a List or iterate through the LinearLayout's children at a later date.

Comment: Beier, Thanks a lot, I can now add my AXML layout, but only one time. By the way, i'm interested in the second part. I will try adding a custom view (even if now I don't know what this means ^^ I'm going to study). And how could I store them after?

Comment: really there is NO documentation in c# about custom views? I can't fine anything...